# Discord.js mentioning user by ID or name

Tags: javascript, discord

`user = message.mentions.members.first();`
This apparently stands for the actual ping of the user.

How would I make it so I can access by user id or name instead? Like for example, if I wanna check someone's money balance in my bot, normally it would be like $bal @user, but I wanna know how to make it so I can do something like $bal [ID]    or $bal [name(without ping)]

Comment: Could you describe your problem in more details? What do you mean by without ping here? `$bal [name(without ping)]`

Comment: `message.author.username` is the username of the person who sent message.. also `message.author.discriminator` is their tag.. so i would print name like `\`${message.author.username}#${message.author.discriminator}\``

Answer (score 0):

To find a member in a guild with the id or the username/tag,

```js
const string = "" //Lets say this holds the id, username, or tag
const user = message.guild.members.cache.get(string) || message.guild.members.cache.find(m => m.user.tag.toLowerCase() == string.toLowerCase()) || message.guild.members.cache.find(m => m.nickname.toLowerCase() == string.toLowerCase())
/*
This first, tries to find the member by searching by IDs, then if that returns null, search by tag, 
then by nickname
*/
```