# How do I mention a person using Discord.js with only the user id?

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to build a bot which mentions people on discord. I already have the usernames of people, and I've been trying to mention users with this :

```
function discordsend(usern)
{ 
string = "$add-money"+usern+"1";
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('channelid');
channel.send(string)
console.log(channel);
}
```

However, it just sends the message plainly to the channel without actually mentioning the user. Is there any way I could mention a user just using their user id ? (Username with Discriminator)

I've also heard I can mention users if I have their IDs, but I only have their User IDs. If there is a way to obtain IDs from UserIDs, please let me know !

FYI, UserID is in the form user#discriminator

Comment: You can get their actual ID using their name and use that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65088993/discord-js-mentioning-user-by-id-or-name but the real solution is don't use usernames, you should be using IDs in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Discord uses a special syntax to embed mentions in a message. For user mentions, it is the user's ID with `<@` at the start and `>` at the end, like this:

```js
<@12345678912345678>
```

If they have a nickname, there will also be a `!` after the `@`.

Comment: Not sure how it answers OP's question. Please, read the question again. They store `user#discriminator`, not the ID.

Answer (score 0):

If I read your question correctly, you wanted to mention a member using their ID only, to use their ID you need to `cache.get`:

```
const member = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
```

if you're familiar with `args` functions then you can use it too with `channels` and `roles`

If you wanted to ping them in bot's messages. you can use `${member}`
for example:

```
message.channel.send(`${member}`)
```

Comment: dumb question, but where do I get the 'message' class from to call message.guild.members.cache.get() ?

Comment: I have tried client.guilds.cache.get(serverid).members.cache.get(userid) but it returns an undefined value !

Comment: What do you wanted to do actually?

Comment: I want to mention someone in a specific channel, while only having their user ID (which I might be getting from, say an excel sheet)

Comment: Well you only need to do the first code i gave, u dont need to get the server id and the channel id,

Comment: I tried this 

function discordsend(usern,message)
{   const userid = message.guild.members.cache.get(usern);
console.log(usern);
console.log(userid);
string = "$add-money <@"+userid+"> 1";
const channel = client.channels.cache.get('946932969359179786');
channel.send(string)
console.log(channel);
}

I get an error that 'guild' is undefined and cannot be read. Any idea what to do ?